# running node with loader ts-node/esm.js requires imports to have the .js extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I am trying to run node 14 with my package.json set as module:

```json
"type": "module",
```

If I run this command on a typescript file:

```sh
 node --loader ts-node/esm.mjs --experimental-top-level-await ./src/scripts/ts-build.ts --trace-warnings --experimental-json-modules
```

and I have extensionless imports like this in a typescript file

```js
import { logger } from './logger';
```

I get

> ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND

But if I change it to

```js
import { logger } from './logger.js';
```

It works.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at the spec there's [this section](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_customizing_esm_specifier_resolution_algorithm) which states:

> The current specifier resolution does not support all default behavior
> of the CommonJS loader. One of the behavior differences is automatic
> resolution of file extensions and the ability to import directories
> that have an index file.

There's another [section](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs) which states:

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword.
> Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully
> specified.

So it seems that the extension is actually necessary. Howvever, there's the [option](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_customizing_esm_specifier_resolution_algorithm) `--experimental-specifier-resolution` which you try setting to `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node`.

Answer (score 10):

I solved it with these experimental features on Node `v14.15.0`.

```
node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node your/entry.ts
```

But if you just want command `node`, `ts-node` or `webpack serve` to work with typescript entry files with import statements(such as server.ts or webpack.config.ts), you can resolve the issue by setting `compilerOptions` under `ts-node` option in your tsconfig.ts.

```
{
    "ts-node": {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "CommonJS"
        }
    },
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "ES6",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        // below entries are just examples
        "src/**/*",
        "server.ts"
        "webpack.config.ts"
    ]
}
```